# How to create a custom convolution operation with a trainable Kernel in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to make a custom layer in Keras that will perform fuzzy operations instead of the sum and product that is done in convolution.

I have already done the convolution operation on a separate project and the code is as follows:

```
activation_map = np.random.random((img_x - kern_x + 1, img_y - kern_y + 1))

for i in range(activation_map.shape[0]):
    for j in range(activation_map.shape[1]):
        activation_map[i][j] = t_conorm(weighting(scaled_matrix[i:i+kern_x,j:j+kern_y],kern))

print(activation_map)
```

Here, kern_x and kern_y are the dimensions of the 2D kernel. img_x and img_y are that of the input image. I have used a 28x28 image and 3x3 kernel. Both the image and the kernel are numpy arrays.

How do I implement it as a custom layer in Keras? I have looked at the documentation of Keras on how to build custom layers and I am finding it quite hard to understand. I need the kernel to be trainable.

This is what I have done till now:

```
class F_Conv2D(Layer):

    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        super(F_Conv2D, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel', 
                                      shape=(3,3),
                                      initializer='uniform',
                                      trainable=True)
        super(F_Conv2D, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end

    def call(self, x):
        # return K.dot(x, self.kernel)
        kern_x,kern_y = self.kernel.eval().shape
        img_x,img_y = x.eval().shape
        fuzzy_activation_map = np.random.random((img_x - kern_x + 1, img_y - kern_y + 1))

        for i in range(activation_map.shape[0]):
            for j in range(activation_map.shape[1]):
                fuzzy_activation_map[i][j] = t_conorm(weighting(scaled_matrix[i:i+kern_x,j:j+kern_y],kern))

        return fuzzy_activation_map



    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.output_dim)
```